# Sin imagenes al hacer el .exe de AutoPyToExe

Tags: python, interfaz-gráfica, pyqt5

Tengo un problema, al momento de hacer el .exe con AutoPyToExe

Carga todo bien, la APP, la Base de Datos y el Archivo .ui (Lo hice en qtpy5), el problema que tengo es que al abrir el .exe no se muestran las imágenes que van dentro de la APP (Ya intenté subir las imágenes por separado en AutoPyToExe). ¿Alguien sabe algo al respecto?

Se ve así:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVgks.png

Cuando se debería de ver así:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCVoN.png

(Ignoren los espacios, sólo importan los íconos)

Comment: Hola Cruz Antonio Gastelum, la pregunta debe ser autocontenida, esto es que no dependa de imágenes o enlaces, por favor, edita tu pregunta elimina la imagen, y agrega tu código y el mensaje de error como texto, gracias. 
Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo resolví!
Mi error era que tenía las imagenes dentro de la carpeta "Descargas" de mi PC y al momento de cargarlas en el archivo .ui se quedaba el directorio de Descargas, lo que hice fue cambiar la direccion de todas las imagenes a donde se encontraba el main.py y funcionó.

Comment: @Mateo perfe!! no me di cuenta...